Symbols in a bash prompt?
This is my bash prompt:
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[34m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[32m\]\n>>> \e(B\e[m"

That gives me a nice prompt:
~/path/to/dir/in/green (git_branch_name_in_blue)
>>>  

Instead of the simple >>>, I'd like to use one of the awesome symbols: ∴ → ☿ ★.
How do I do that?
I tried many things, for example adding \[\e[31m\]\xe2\x98\x85  at the end
PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[34m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[32m\]\n> \e(B\e[m \[\e[31m\]\xe2\x98\x85 "`

but I end up with this as a prompt:
>>>  \xe2\x98\x85 

Did you try just replacing the > with one of your symbols right there in whatever file you are showing us? You have the definition of your PS1 there, so what happens if you use one of those symbols?

@terdon Tried many, but no success.

Like what? Come on, don't make us guess! If you have tried things, show them to us so we don't waste your time and ours giving you solutions you have tried. What did you try? How exactly did it fail?

If your terminal font supports UTF-8 characters, you could copy-paste all characters as-is in your script (i.e. https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_technical.asp)
PS1='UTF-8 chars: \e[31m∴ \e[32m→ \e[33m☿ \e[34m★ \e[0m > '

You can search for ANSI, color CSI sequences on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

"If your terminal font supports UTF-8 characters..." - if it doesn't support UTF8 you'll not get the characters displayed anyway

Copy-paste works, thanks...!
